# Base64 string only works in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, base64

This is kind on an odd problem.

I have a scanner that can returns the scanned images in a base64 string.  However, when I use that string to set an img tag's src property, it ONLY works in IE.

For example, my HTML tag ends up looking something like this:

```
<img id="img_buf" src"data:image/gif;base64,SUkqAAgAAAARAP4ABAABAA...." />
```

The problem is that the string that this only works in IE.  I've seen problems before where the base64 string didn't work in IE, but I haven't encountered the opposite scenario.  Is there any way to use javascript to convert the string to a base64 string that will work cross-browser?

Update:

Ok, in order to be more clear, here's the complete HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>IMG Data Sample</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function LoadImg()
            {
                var imgStr1 = "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";

                var imgStr2 = "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";

                document.getElementById("img_buf1").src = "data:image/tiff;base64," + imgStr1;
                document.getElementById("img_buf2").src = "data:image/tiff;base64," + imgStr2;
            }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body onload="LoadImg()">

        <img id="img_buf1" alt="Cannot Display Image..." />

        <br />
        <br />

        <img id="img_buf2" alt="Cannot Display Image..." />

    </body>

</html>
```

Try it out.  Copy the code above into Notepad, save it as test.html on the desktop, and open it with different browsers.  In IE, both img tags show an image.  However, in Chrome of Firefox, only the bottom img tag displays an image, and the top img tag displays the alt text.

I got the value of imgStr2 by passing the value of imgStr1 through a C# program that I wrote:

```
// imgStr1 in the HTML
string orgString = "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";

byte[] orgByte = Convert.FromBase64String(orgString);
MemoryStream byteMs = new MemoryStream(orgByte, 0, orgByte.Length);
byteMs.Write(orgByte, 0, orgByte.Length);
Image img = Image.FromStream(byteMs, true);

MemoryStream b64Ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(b64Ms, ImageFormat.Png);
byte[] newByte = b64Ms.ToArray();
string newString = Convert.ToBase64String(newByte);

// I'm copying the output from the text box and setting the value of imgStr2 with it
textBox1.Text = newString;
```

You can see that the C# code is basically just changing the image format and converting it back to a Base64 string.  If push comes to shove, I could just send the value back to my C# server-side code and return the reformatted Base64 string.  However, I'd like to avoid the extra server call by doing what the C# code is doing with Javascript on the client-side if possible.

My question: is it possible to do this with Javascript?

Comment: Is this a duplicate issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114759/showing-base64string-as-image-works-in-ie-but-not-in-chrome

Comment: You sure the image is actually a gif?

Comment: I've tried a bunch of MIME types (png, tiff, jpg).  It doesn't make a difference.  In all cases, it works in IE, not in anything else.

Comment: And I don't think it's a duplicate.  I saw that post and checked in both browsers.  The value of the src attribute is the same in both.  It renders in IE, but not in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: What there appears in other browsers? Nothing? Just a pixel-mass? Something else?

Comment: In non-ie browsers, the place holder icon for bad images appears in place of the image.  It's the same as if the source is pointing to a file that doesn't exist and no alt is specified - that icon.

Comment: Can't you check the scanner settings, what is the actual file format it creates, and maybe adjust the format?

Comment: In short, no.  Somebody else's program creates that string.  I have to work with what I'm given.

Comment: It looks like you're being given a **TIFF** image. This has not got wide browser support, you [**can't simply include it differently**](http://www.alternatiff.com/howtoembed.html). See if you can produce other formats or if you can convert it server side first. **tl;dr only IE supports `.tif` files**